# keeping scope while using import statment

Tags: javascript

I have three scripts: main.js, helper.js and module1.js. I need to include module1.js in helper.js, buf if I do this I'm getting an error message. It seems like the moment I use the tpye="module" tag on helper.js it's scope shifts. So how do I achieve the following without an error: (I don't want to make helper.js a module, which would solve the problem, because than I have to manualy import everything.)

index.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="module" src='helper.js'></script>
        <script type="module" src='main.js'></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

module1.js

```
export { f1 }

function f1() {
    /* DIFFERENT STUFF */
    return 0;
}
```

main.js

```
// import THINGS from STUFF;

(() => {/*STUFF*/})();

let res = importantValue;
```

helper.js

```
import { f1 } from "./module1.js";

const importantValue = f1();
```

Error Message:

```
main.js: Uncaught ReferenceError: importantValue is not defined
```

Comment: That's not how modules work. You'd have to use `export const importValue = f1()` (or `export { importantValue }`) and then `import { importantValue } from './helper.js`. But if you really don't want to make it a module (why? it would be so much cleaner...) then you can use `window.importantValue = importantValue` in the helper file.

Comment: Did you export the `importantValue` from `helper.js` ?

Comment: @CherryDT so the moment I start using "import" I lose the scope of the "main window" (still new to JS)? And "window" is just a reference to my global scope?
--> Meaning I have to either not use modules at all or use them for basicly every file.
On that note: Can I bundle modules together so that my import statements are less of a mess? E.g. Importing module1.js and module2.js in one line or something like that?